# How to manipulate FieldTypes in Poly1?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I wanted to use sequence from shapeless contrib (+scalaz) on Labelled Generics, but first I need to map over FieldTypes.

Is it's possible to create the missing f function in that exemple ?

```
object TestLabelledGeneric {

  import shapeless._

  import singleton._


  val a = "name" ->> Option("hello") :: "y" ->> Option(1) :: HNil

  val b = Option("name" ->> "hello") :: Option("y" ->> 1) :: HNil

  val f = ???

  val name = Witness('name); val age = Witness('age)

  def assertTypedEquals[A](expected: A, actual: A): Unit = assert(expected == actual)

  assertTypedEquals[b.type](b, a.map(f))


}
```

SOLVED, Thanks @travis-brown !

Here is the version that works on my machine :

```
object TestLabelledGeneric {

  import shapeless._

  import singleton._

  val a = "name" ->> Option("hello") :: "y" ->> Option(1) :: HNil

  val b = Option("name" ->> "hello") :: Option("y" ->> 1) :: HNil

  import labelled.{ FieldType, field }

  object f extends Poly1 {
    implicit def kv[K, V]: Case.Aux[
      FieldType[K, Option[V]],
      Option[FieldType[K, V]]
      ] =
      at(_.map(field[K](_)))
  }

  // If I try to use Witness.`"name"`.T directly in Res, I have a "not accessible type" error
  val name = Witness.`"name"`
  val y = Witness.`"y"`
  type Res = Option[FieldType[name.T, String]] :: Option[FieldType[y.T ,Int]] :: HNil

  def assertTypedEquals[A](expected: A, actual: A): Unit = assert(expected == actual)

  assertTypedEquals[Res](b, a.map(f))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to convert a `FieldType[K, Option[V]]` into an `Option[FieldType[K, V]]`. `FieldType[K, Option[V]]` is a subtype of `Option[V]`, and you can turn the `V` into a `FieldType[K, V]` with `shapeless.labelled.field`.

Then you can put this operation into a `Poly1`:

```
import shapeless._, labelled.{ FieldType, field }, syntax.singleton._

object f extends Poly1 {
  implicit def kv[K, V]: Case.Aux[
    FieldType[K, Option[V]],
    Option[FieldType[K, V]]
  ] =
    at(_.map(field[K](_)))
}
```

This doesn't get you quite what you want, since the type of `a.map(f)` isn't `b.type` (which is the singleton type for `b`). You can confirm that it actually does what you want, though:

```
scala> type Res =
     |   Option[FieldType[Witness.`"name"`.T, String]] ::
     |   Option[FieldType[Witness.`"y"`.T, Int]] :: HNil
defined type alias Res

scala> assertTypedEquals[Res](b, a.map(f))
```

So yep, they're the same.